# Where are buildroot BR2 options documented?

Tags: buildroot

Is there a central place where all BR2 options used in config and defconfig files for buildroot are documented?

At the moment, I'm looking for ways to customize the buildroot target devicetree.  I've stumbled across options BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME, BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_DTS, and BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH, but no documentation that tells me how to use them.

When searching for that documentation, I realized that I couldn't find a complete list of BR2 options and what they do. Does such a list exist? The buildroot manual does describe some BR2 options, but apparently not all of them.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - please read the entire page and not just the short list at the top. Requests for us to find off-site resources (which includes documentation links) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those options are documented in Kconfig environment. Just perform `make menuconfig`, select *Kernel* submenu, find one of DTS options and press `H`. You'll get a help text like this:

```
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Compile one or more device tree sources into device tree                                                                                                                                                                          
blobs.                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Select the dts files to compile in the options below.
```

Most likely you need `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH`.

Comment: The challenge that I'm having is knowing what to look for in the first place.  Is there any way to generate a searchable help report for everything in `make menuconfig`?  That would make it easier to hunt for keywords such as `DTS` and `device tree` without knowing where to find them in the menus.

Comment: I don't know if you can exports the texts, but you can search there. See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38033/50162).

Comment: @edj - I know it might be to late to response, but if you press [SHIFT] + [/] then you can search for keywords like DTS. Then, in the search result just press the number next to the description.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you close.  At least all the help will be in one file for you to peruse at your leisure:

```
    $ mkdir ~/tmp
    $ cd <path_to>/buildroot<version>$ for f in `find . -name *.in`; do cat $f >> ~/tmp/in-files; done;
    $ vi ~/tmp/in-files
```

You could also extend the 'do' portion to include using awk, sed, or grep so that you only extract the 'help' bits and not the rest of the configuration input stuff.